# My table in lua only print nil when I use "for" to fill it

Tags: lua

I would like to contruct a configuration file with the code :
  But, my code is  wrong, why ? the final line only print nil, nil, nil...

```
-- Define ten network interfaces
interfaces = {} -- Define an empty table
for n = 1, 10 do
interfaces[n] = {
device = "eth"..n,
address = "192.168.1."..n
}
end
for k, v in pairs(interfaces) do print(device,address) end
```

Comment: BTW, there's also https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua

Answer (score 2):

In the code below, the names `device` and `address` are resolved as global variables that are undefined. Hence the nils in the output.

```
for k, v in pairs(interfaces) do print(device,address) end
```

Try this instead:

```
for k, v in pairs(interfaces) do print(v.device,v.address) end
```

Since the order of pairs traversed by `pairs` is not defined, use `ipairs` if you need the list to be output in order.

Comment: Thank you ihf, this resolve my problem. Very simple answer, I was trying when I read this article https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi8-ef026DbAhWBiJAKHQqACZAQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.netbsd.org%2F~mbalmer%2Flua%2Flua_config.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1IglcwtjwVGyNZ0FRtX8jn  . Could be a lua version problem ?